# Ubuntu 17.10 gnome keyboard shortcut Super-F1 can not be reset to other GUI action

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-3, ubuntu-17.10

I install a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 on my thinkpad x230i notepad. I change the login method to x11org gnome. After login, if I press Super-F1, the gnome help window will be launched. I want to change this keyboard shortcut to other GUI action. What I had done:

1. I tried to change it by Settings-Devices-Keyboard-Custom shortcuts,
   but failed to assign Super-F1 to a custom shortcut item.
2. I also tired to reset it by editing the custom shortcut item in
   dconf
   Editor with the path /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/binding,
   although the value can be changed successfully, when I press
   Super-F1, the gnome help still can be launched.
3. Even I delete the
   gnome help, the shortcut Super-F1 still can not be assign to other
   GUI action.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: it is not possible to reassign `<Super>+<F1>` in Gnome v3.21.9x+.

The long answer: starting with Gnome version 3.21.90 there's a *hardcoded* assignment of Super+F1 to Gnome Help, so you can't reassign this key combination without recompiling `gnome-settings-daemon` (and, more specifically, the `gsd-media-keys` plugin).

According to gnome-settings-daemon [changelog](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/blob/master/NEWS):

```
===============
Version 3.21.90
===============
...
 Media keys:
    - Add Super+F1 as a hardcoded shortcut for launching Help
...
```

Looking at the source code (file [.../plugins/media-keys/shortcuts-list.h](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/blob/master/plugins/media-keys/shortcuts-list.h)) you'll find:

```
...
  { HELP_KEY, NULL, N_("Help"), "<Super>F1", GSD_ACTION_MODE_LAUNCHER },
...
```

I was able to successfully recompile the gnome-settings-daemon binary, but it took me a few hours to get everything right. I wrote a [detailed step-by-step](https://wrgms.com/fixing-gnome-3-2x-hardcoded-superf1-shortcut/), but here's a summary:

1. Download and install [Gnome Builder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder)
2. "Clone" the official repo at `https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon`
3. Go to the directory where you downloaded the repo, and checkout your specific version with `git checkout tag/GNOME_SETTINGS_DAEMON_3_28_1` (make sure this matches your version; check the Gnome version you're running with `gnome-shell --version`, and all the tags available with `git tag -l`).
4. Install dependencies:

   ```
   apt install libcolord-dev, \
               libgeocode-glib-dev, \
               gnome-desktop3-data, \
               libgweather-3-dev, \
               libcanberra-gtk3-dev, \
               libgeoclue-2-dev, \
               libnotify-dev, \
               libpulse-mainloop-glib0, \
               libpulse-dev, \
               gobject-introspection, \
               libupower-glib-dev, \
               libpolkit-gobject-1-dev, \
               libasound2-dev, \
               libgudev-1.0-dev, \
               libwacom-dev, \
               libnss3-dev, \
               libcups2-dev, \
               libnm-dev
   ```
5. Patch the file `./gnome-settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/shortcuts-list.h`, by adding a comment in front of the line with the Super+F1 (around line 69, for v3.28.x)
6. Recompile using Builder
7. Locate the compiled `gsd-media-keys` binary and replace in your system (don't forget to make a copy of the original before proceeding, in the case you need to revert back)
8. Log out or reboot, and you're done!

Now you can re-assign the Super+F1 keys normally to anything you want.

Comment: I have to upvote in admiration of all the trouble you went through to fix this, and the additional trouble you went through to document what you did here.  But I would not fix such a problem by recompiling a module.  I am simply going to live with not being able to reassign Super+F1, and I am making a note that if I ever meet the person responsible for the hard-coding of Super+F1, I should slap them in the face with a salmontrout.